# iOS: Faster to call setNeedsDisplayInRect twice when there are two small, non-adjacent areas of the view that need redrawing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawing, drawrect

Assume that two very small areas of my view need to be redrawn. One is in the upper left corner, the other in the bottom right. I could use their coordinates to pass a single large CGRect that contains both areas to setNeedsDisplayInRect, but this will end up including a lot of other areas that do **not** need to be redrawn.

So the other option would be to simply pass their individual containing CGRects to setNeedsDisplayInRect, one after the next, i.e.

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:rectForArea1]
[self.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:rectForArea2]
```

Which would generally be faster? Minimizing the number of times that drawRect: ultimately gets called, or minimizing the amount of screen area that it has to redraw, even if it must redraw twice?

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter. As described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1708/_index.html), iOS will always update the whole view, independent of what rect you pass into setNeedsDisplayInRect:

> Note that, because of the way that iPhone/iPod touch/iPad updates its
>   screen, the entire view will be redrawn if you call
>   -setNeedsDisplayInRect: or -setNeedsDisplay:.

Answer (score 0):

it is depending upon that two rect.

if both bounds addition are  75% of view bounds then i will call simply call

```
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

because we draw almost whole view.

if both bounds addition are below 50% of view bounds then i will call simply call

```
    [self.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:rectForArea1];

    [self.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:rectForArea2];
```

because we need to draw small spaces

Comment: Can you provide anything to back up these choices? For example, it seems to me that simply calling setNeedsDisplay any time the re-drawing area is over 75% of the screen is a bit lazy. Although the re-drawing is most of the screen, you're still redrawing quite a bit that you don't need to, so it could be made more efficient. And depending on what you have in that last 25% of the screen, that extra re-drawing could be quite expensive.

Comment: if u dont care about number of times the needdisplay method calling then go ahead with only draw rect

Comment: But I do care. The whole purpose of my post is to find out which is the most efficient way to achieve the same thing. So if calling drawRect: multiple times on different small CGRects is more expensive than calling it once on a large CGRect, i'd prefer to do that. And vice versa.

Comment: it depends upon ur app needs. u have to choose